# Copying game files from friend who also owns the game Steam?

Tags: steam

My friend and I recently purchased Rainbow Six: Siege on Steam. However I have a very limited data plan so I can't download. Can I copy the game contents from his PC to mine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you can**.

The only check Steam is doing, is that you have Steam running with a logged account possessing the game when you launch a steam game.

So you can totally take the game on the computer of your friend where he installed it and copy it into your Steam games directory.

Comment: @Saad No problem. I have a slow Internet connection like you so I always try to take large games on the computers of friends to not have to wait the entire night with my PC downloading. ;)

Comment: @Saad And if the answer is good enough for you, don't forget to accept it so that we know your problem is resolved.